# Как вывести в div результат ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Получаю ответ в json от ajax запроса и пытаюсь вывести в `<div class="writeinfo"></div>`

```
 success: function (data) { 
      $(".writeinfo").html(data); 
    }
```

Как мне распарсить и вывести значения циклом, сейчас только выводит в div

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Json приходит такой

```
[[{"id":1,"date_event":"2020-01-17","created_at":"2020-01-23 23:00:00","updated_at":null,"user_id":15}]]
```

Comment: JSON.stringify(data); ?

Comment: В <div class="writeinfo"></div> ничего не выводит

Comment: где вы смотрите, какой приходит json и как?

Comment: Через отладку в браузере Сеть

Comment: настройте ajax на получение html, а не json

Comment: Как настроить ?

Answer (score 0):

```
array = JSON.parse(data)
```

далее можно работать как с обычным массивом